# Unable to access Docusign Admin

Tags: docusignapi

Recently we have purchased a production account. I have logged into the account as Account Administrator but I am unable to see Docusign Admin. This was not the case for the developer account where it was already present from beforehand.

I need it as I have to add an organisation.

Below I have added a picture of how it looks in dev account.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you had "Admin" in Demo, then someone had to add that as it is not provided by default.  Admin tools (Org Management and Access Management w/ SSO) are only included in the Enterprise Pro plan.  For Business Pro or Standard plans, it is a paid add-on.  Check to see if your account is an Enterprise Pro plan.

Also, if your company already has Org Mgmt, a "DocuSign Admin" (org, not account admin) needs to link this new account to the Org.

Answer (score 0):

So, most likely you have someone else in your company who is the admin. You will to find out who that is.
Every account has to have one admin at all times. You don't see to have administrative rights, but someone else may have.
If not, or if you don't know who that is - you will need to contact customer support to get this restored and take over as admin.

Another option is that you have multiple accounts in production. Meaning, when you log in, your user is a member of more than one account. You need to switch accounts. That switcher is an option on the right-top menu.